# Will video and photo editing wear out a 2015 macbook pro's SSD significantly?

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, video-editing

I plan on buying the latest 2015 13" Macbook pro while travelling for video and photo editing (among other activities such as programming). The SSD size will probably be 256 or 512gb along with a 2TB WD passport external I own.

Will transferring a large amount of video clips to the SSD and deleting after completion regularly wear out my Macbook pro's lifetime significantly or only by an unnoticeable time?

Comment: For what values of significantly? For what values of large? Why not buy it and then measure the IO for 6 months. At that point, you can either self-insure against the failure or buy AppleCare and then Apple's on the hook for 3 years of whatever workload you care to place on the Mac?

Answer (score 1):

SSD's have been [found to be quite durable](http://techreport.com/review/27436/the-ssd-endurance-experiment-two-freaking-petabytes). That article goes into depth with respect to SSD issues, and they performed hardware tests upon several manufacture of SSD.

Comment: What does the RAID security entail?

Comment: It will mainly be used while on the go, so the RAID is not really an option for me. I will only carry a normal 2TB external WD hard drive to backup files

Comment: @bmike: A RAID is two-or-more hard drives running in parallel, all of them storing the same data that would otherwise be written to a single drive. Presumably, only one drive will fail at a time, which can be easily replaced by a new drive to continue storing data in paralle.

Comment: @rikket: Fair enough. It wasn't clear whether you were using the 2TB drive for extra storage, or for backup. Aside from that, per the article about testing SSD durability, it sounds like there shouldn't be issue with using the macbook as a workhorse.

Comment: RAID doesn't imply mirroring - and there are significant downsides to using software RAID such as you [lose the Recovery HD](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/119164/5472) and thereby the ability to Filevault 2. I was curious if it somehow related to usage of SSD or if you were just throwing that in as a general recommendation.

Comment: @bmike: I threw that as a recommendation because the OP was concerned about loss of image/video data, and it wasn't clear until later comments that the 2TB WD was for backups. If you look at that link for 6TB WD, it supports RAID 1 configuration, which might have been useful depending upon OP's anxiety over data loss.

Comment: I'm going to edit the raid part out. If you or the OP want to ask a follow on question about backups, feel free.